# How to find the minmal bounding rectangles for a set of lines?

Tags: algorithm, graphics, geometry, 2d

Provided a set of N connected lines on a 2D axis, I am looking for an algorithm which will determine the X minimal bounding rectangles.

For example, suppose I am given 10 lines and I would like to bound them with at most 3 (potentially intersecting) rectangles. So if 8 of the lines are clustered closely together, they may use 1 rectangle, and the other two may use a 2nd or perhaps also a 3rd rectangle depending on their proximity to each other.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what you want to minimize: number of rectangles? aggregated area of the rectangles? Something else?

Comment: aggregated area. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. Now I think of it, however, you need more restrictions, or you could just make a super tiny rectangle around each point (as many rectangles as points) and you'd be done

Comment: OK. I made a mistake here.  I actually want to bound lines connecting the points, not the points themselves. And in most cases, i never want more than 4 rectangles so just bounding the lines themselves individually would not suffice. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry to keep asking, I'm just missing details: are all your points connected to each other with lines? Because the only way to get things in a rectangle without intersecting with lines is to actually make a single rectangle that (just barely) includes all the points. Also, could you edit your question so the next person that reads this gets your point without reading through our little thread? ;)

Comment: Maybe draw a picture? This one's interesting, but I can't tell if you mean N lines that intersect, form a polygon or what.

Comment: Let me clarify.  The lines are connected but the end point does not connect to the start point.  Think of a 1 trip across the country. The route line, for example, does not connect end points and thus does not create a polygon.

Answer (score 2):

If the lines are actually a path, then perhaps you wouldn't be averse to the requirement that each rectangle cover a contiguous portion of the path. In this case, there's a dynamic program that runs in time O(n<sup>2</sup> r), where n is the number of segments and r is the number of rectangles.

Compute a table with entries C(i, j) denoting the cost of covering segments 1, …, i with j rectangles. The recurrence is, for i, j > 0,

> C(0, 0) = 0
>   C(i, 0) = ∞
>   C(i, j) = min over i' < i of (C(i', j - 1) + [cost of the rectangle covering segments i' + 1, …, i])

There are O(n r) entries, each of which is computed in time O(n). Recover the optimal collection of rectangles at the end by, e.g., storing the best i' for each entry.

I don't know of a simple, optimal algorithm for the general case. Since there are “only” O(n<sup>4</sup>) rectangles whose edges each contain a segment endpoint, I would be tempted to formulate this problem as an instance of generalized set cover.